# Reversing order of children

Tags: xslt

I want to use templates to reverse the different sequences of XML;
For example :

```
<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
  <author first="Priscilla" />
  <chapter title="[I] ">
    <section title="[I.1]" />
    <section title="[I.2]">
      <section title="[I.2.1]" />
      <section title="[I.2.2]" />
    </section>
    <section title="[I.3] ">
      <section title="[I.3.1]" />
    </section>
  </chapter>
  <chapter title="[II]">
    <section title="[II.1]" />
    <section title="[II.2]">
      <section title="[II.2.1]" />
      <section title="[II.2.2]" />
    </section>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

I want to get the output like this:this is my xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
   <author first="Priscilla"/>
   <chapter title="[I]">
      <section title="[I.3]">
         <section title="[I.3.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[I.2]">
         <section title="[I.2.2]"/>
         <section title="[I.2.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[I.1]"/>
   </chapter>
   <chapter title="[II]">
      <section title="[II.2]">
         <section title="[II.2.2]"/>
         <section title="[II.2.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[II.1]"/>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Yes,the sections have been reversed but the chapters are not.

I try to use two templates to solve it,but it can not work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml"  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent ="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:sequence select="@title"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="author"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter">
    <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="section"/>

     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match ="chapter|section" as="element()">
  <xsl:param name="seq" as="element(section)*"/>
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:sequence select="@title"/>
     <xsl:if test="not(empty($seq))">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter">
        <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq[position()>1]"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$seq[1]"/>    
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I don't see any differences between first and second xml. But if you want to use some different templates more than one time - read about "mode" attribute in templates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256110.aspx)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and simplest/shortest solution presented at present. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a simpler XSLT 1.0 (and 2.0) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[section]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:sort select="position()"
      data-type="number" order="descending"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
  <author first="Priscilla" />
  <chapter title="[I] ">
    <section title="[I.1]" />
    <section title="[I.2]">
      <section title="[I.2.1]" />
      <section title="[I.2.2]" />
    </section>
    <section title="[I.3] ">
      <section title="[I.3.1]" />
    </section>
  </chapter>
  <chapter title="[II]">
    <section title="[II.1]" />
    <section title="[II.2]">
      <section title="[II.2.1]" />
      <section title="[II.2.2]" />
    </section>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

**the wanted, correct result (all sequences of `section` elements reversed) is produced** :

```
<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
   <author first="Priscilla"/>
   <chapter title="[I] ">
      <section title="[I.3] ">
         <section title="[I.3.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[I.2]">
         <section title="[I.2.2]"/>
         <section title="[I.2.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[I.1]"/>
   </chapter>
   <chapter title="[II]">
      <section title="[II.2]">
         <section title="[II.2.2]"/>
         <section title="[II.2.1]"/>
      </section>
      <section title="[II.1]"/>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:thanks for your good answered,If I do not want to use  element <xsl:sort>,and want to use  <xsl:template match="chapter|section"> as well ,what can i do for that?

Comment: @ZAWD: `<xsl:sort>` was designed exactly with the purpose of presenting the results of applying templates (and of `<xsl:for-each>`) when the desired order of the results of processing of each node is not the default (document) order. If due to some unexplainable reason you don't want to use `<xsl:sort>`, then theoretically you could always process the last element, then apply templates on the partial results so far. Definitely, this is extremely inappropriate.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:Yeah,I try to make it in this way.creating a template and call it ,but it is a long story ,I want to make it shorter,but without <xsl:sort>..  :)  <xsl:template name="rev" as="element(section)*">
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="element(section)*"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(empty($seq))">
      <xsl:call-template name="rev">
        <xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq[position()>1]"/>
   </xsl:call-template><section title="{$seq[1]/@title}"><xsl:call-template name="rev"><xsl:with-param name="seq" select="$seq[1]/section"/></xsl:call-template></section></xsl:if> </xsl:template>

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:If i do not want to use <xsl:sort>,what can i do that??

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:I've updated my xsl, but the result is wrong, could you help me

Comment: @ZAWD: You say that you don't want to use `<xsl:sort>` but have accepted an answer that uses just that. Why?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:I am sorry ,I just want to find another way to solve the problem.  : )

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="chapter|section">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="tokenize(@title,'.')[last()]"
                          order="descending"
                          data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
    <author first="Priscilla"/>
    <chapter title="[I] ">
        <section title="[I.3] ">
            <section title="[I.3.1]"/></section>
        <section title="[I.2]">
            <section title="[I.2.2]"/>
            <section title="[I.2.1]"/></section>
        <section title="[I.1]"/>
    </chapter>
    <chapter title="[II]">
        <section title="[II.2]">
            <section title="[II.2.2]"/>
            <section title="[II.2.1]"/></section>
        <section title="[II.1]"/>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: Why such an unnecessarily complex solution?

Comment: @ZAWD: You should see twice ;)

Comment: @Dimitre: Is not complex. Just it doesn't rely on an ordered input.

Comment: @Alejandro: The OP wants to reverse the order of section elements -- elements in a document are always in document order.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev:"elements in a document are always in document order. "I am no clear what is it meant....

Comment: @ZAWS: Try both solutions with this input: `<book title="Definitive XML Schema">
 <author first="Priscilla" />
 <chapter title="[I] ">
  <section title="[I.1]" />
  <section title="[I.3] ">
   <section title="[I.3.1]" />
  </section>
  <section title="[I.2]">
   <section title="[I.2.2]" />
   <section title="[I.2.1]" />
  </section>
 </chapter>
 <chapter title="[II]">
  <section title="[II.1]" />
  <section title="[II.2]">
   <section title="[II.2.2]" />
   <section title="[II.2.1]" />
  </section>
 </chapter>
</book>`

Comment: @ZAWD: Unless a reverse axis is used in an XPath expression, the `position()` function returns the position of the context node in the current node-list *in document order*. This is why the `<xsl:sort>` instruction is used to output the selected nodes in some other order. "Document order" is the order of nodes in a depth-first serialization of a tree (the same you see looking at an xml document serialized as text).

Comment: @Alejandro:If i do not want to use <xsl:sort>,what can i do that??

Comment: @ZAWD: It depends. I think you should ask a new question clarifying your request.